# I need to connect to Google cloud mysql using java but without using spring boot?

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

can someone help me with any sample working code or any project that I can look at? I have been searching this on google for few days but I always end up an answer with spring boot but I need to connect without using spring boot. I need to write automated API tests where I have to connect to cloud Sql fetch the data from Db and validate it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app)? Also, please have a look at the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and add more info regarding the issues you are experiencing when trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@siamsot** mentioned, there is an [**article**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) in the official GCP documentation on how to connect to a Cloud SQL instance.

Basically, you have the following options to **connect to a Cloud SQL instance**:

- By using the [proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) (Second Generation instances only)
- By [configuring access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) for one or more public IP addresses
- By using the [JDBC Socket Factory](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java) (for the Java programming language,
  Second Generation instances only)
- By using the Cloud SQL [Proxy library](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#python) (for the Go programming language, Second Generation instances only)